# xlsm file locked for editing by another user - error

Tags: excel, vba

I have an .xlsm file which was working good for the last 2 weeks and all of a sudden it says "Locked for editing by another User". There are no users having that file opened.

Could it be a problem with the VBA Code inside the File? The last time when this macro was run the xlsm file was closed without saving the changes.

Comment: is this file on a network server? local file?

Comment: Its on the network server

Comment: the server has it open, ask admin to kill the file then you should be good.

Comment: Thanks ! I suppose it can't be a problem with the VBA Coding isn't it ?

Comment: i don't think so. unless you share some of the code here.

Comment: Its a huge one around 30 Subs. So, I don't think its okay to share all of them over here. Also, the next thing it says is - "we found a problem with some content in this file"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148810/discussion-between-pokemon-man-and-sid29).

Comment: is there a ~$youractualfilename.xlsm file in the directory? Delete that one and try again